# Timoshenko Beam with sliding boundary conditions at angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, boundary-conditions, structural-beam

I would like to calculate the effective stiffness of a structure which can be represented as follows:

[image: Structure representation] (Image source: [Link to paper with image.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822319309377))

The yellow part is flexible and the blue is a rigid-body-like part. In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822319309377) a derivation for this structure under the assumption that the yellow strut can be modeled as an Euler-Bernoulli beam is shown.

For my analysis I need to consider the yellow part to be a Timoshenko-beam, since the thickness (h(x)) is too big to be modeled as an Euler-Bernoulli beam.

Is there an expression for a beam with this boundary conditions for a Timoshenko-beam at a given angle with respect to the horizontal axis (x-axis)?

I couldn't find such an expression in different mechanical text books (e.g. [Theory of elastic stability, Stephen P. Timoshenko, James M. Gere](https://books.google.at/books/about/Theory_of_Elastic_Stability.html?id=98B6JOW2HiUC&redir_esc=y)), only for beams at 90° with respect to the x-axis.

EDIT (based on comments):

The rotation is no longer the derivative of the deflection but a new degree of freedom, say
$$
\theta(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\mu_3} \chi_{i}(x) r_i
$$
similar to the axial and transverse displacement
$$
u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\mu_3} \psi_{i}(x) p_i, \qquad
w(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\mu_3} \phi_{i}(x) q_i
$$
with
$$
\psi_i(x),\enspace\phi_i(x),\enspace\chi_i(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\left( \frac{(i-1)!}{j!(i-j-1)!)} \right )^2 \left( \frac{x}{L}-1\right)^{i-j-1}\left(\frac{x}{L} \right )^j \enspace (i=1, 2, ...)
$$
being the shifted Legendre polynomials, defined in the domain $[0, L]$.

The potential energy due to bending ($U_M$) and shearing ($U_V$) is then
$$
V = U_M + U_V =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^L E I(x)\left(\frac{d\theta(x)}{dx}\right)^2dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^LKGA(x)\left(\theta(x)-\frac{dw(x)}{dx}\right)^2dx
$$

Then I have to apply Hamilton's principle as described in the paper.

Comment: I think that you have the analysis is the same when using Timoshenko beams.

Comment: @nicoguaro Do you mean, exchange the strain energy expression used in the paper (Euler-Bernoulli) with the one used in a Timoshenko beam?

Comment: Yes. And now the rotation is not the derivative of the deflection but a new degree of freedom.

Comment: @nicoguaro Like in the EDIT of the question?

Comment: I think so. But I also think that you edit should be an answer.

Comment: @nicoguaro I will try to work out an implementation and add an answer once I checked that it's working. Thank you